# how to insert a data into many tables

Tags: sql, sql-insert

For example, I have a 3 table

```
Table name: Role
table Attributes: roleid (pk), rolename
```

role to user one to many

```
Table name: user
table Attributes: roleid (fk), userid(pk), trackingid(fk) username, password, email
```

user to tacking one to one

```
Table name: tracking
table Attributes: trackingid(pk) approvalstatus*, status, createdby, createdDate(yyyy-mm-dd).
```

*meaning of attributes
approval status - admin will approve any changes so it can be pending, approved or rejected

status is to indicated whether the change request is new user/ edit or delete user.

How do I do a insert into statement to insert a new user for approval. As, when you insert the data in the database should look like this

```
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| username | password |       email        | rolename | status | approvalstatus | createdby | createdDate |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| harry    | password | harry@yahoo.com.sg | Admin    | New    | Pending        | Barry     | 2016-09-20  |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please don't tag-spam unrelated products.  Tag the DBMS you're actually using.

Answer (score -1):

This really depends on how you're interacting with the Database.

If you're using an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate, this comes out of the box depending on how you map your tables.

For information on this please view:

1. [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/)

If you're doing this direct to SQL Server you can use the following:

1. Stored Procedure - In this case you'll call a single stored procedure on your DB Server, which will do three inserts for you based on your inputs.
2. You can perform 3 operations to the DB using a single connection.

Regardless of whether you pick a Stored Proc. or manual statement your inserts will look like:

```
INSERT INTO ROLE (RoleID, RoleName) VALUES (newID(), 'Your Role Name'); --If you have auto increment on your PK you can ignore inserting into RoleID. Most Systems I work with now use GUID's for ID's so this is just an example.

INSERT INTO User (RoleID, UserID, TrackingID, UserName, Password, Email) Values (....)

INSERT INTO Tracking (TrackingID, ApprovalStatus, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedDate) values (....)
```

Once you have an entry in your DB you can update that using:

```
UPDATE Tracking SET ApprovalStatus = 'whatever you want here' where id = X
```

IF you need to maintain history of tracking, rather than update Tracking, you need to insert a new row and always make sure when you're SELECT'ing your data, you get the latest one based on the  DateTime stamp.

Your table in your question is misleading. You're joining three tables to get those results, which is maybe what you want on our output.

Comment: Don't down vote an answer without providing comments on why it's down voted.

Comment: just asking if i am using webform asp.net to allow user input. Assuming user have to input the data manually for column in each table. do i have to make a separate webform for each table or can i just use tabs to navigate into different tables.

Comment: You could use a single webform for this, how you display data is not "really" related to how you store it.

Comment: i have more questions. what if i need to import a ton of data from excel. The data in excel will have the ids and and all the attributes (whatever shown in output table + all ids). then **how do i break up that excel/csv data that is  imported into the 3 tables.**

Comment: @taniya0012 - Comments aren't the place to ask more questions. Ask separate questions, but don't bury them here.